# how to delete tbody(forms) were checked when I click button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I add the forms via dataPush function

```
    dataPush(dataType) {
         let dataObject;
              if (dataType == 'bankInfo') {
                 dataObject = {
                    bankIndex: 0,
                    bankOwner: '',
                    bankName: [],
                    bankAccount: '',
                }
          }
    }
```

this is for deleting function, but I have no idea to pass the what is checked form?

```
   dataPull(dataType, index) {
            this[dataType].splice(index, 1);
        },
```

buttons are locationed outside v-for , so I have no idea how I can pass indexes it's checked

Here are more details:

Comment: Please add HTML code directly to the question instead of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an event handler on the checkbox such that it will assign a value to global variable which will be used in the splice operation.

JS:

```
data: {
   selected: [];
}
methods: {
    checkedForm: function (index) {
        // check if checkbox is checked before pushing.
        this.selected.push(index);
    }

    dataPull: function () {
        if (this.selected.length < 1)
            return;

        this.selected.forEach((index) => { 
            this[dataType].splice(index, 1);
        }

        this.selected = [];
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<tbody v-for="(item, index)">
...
<input type="checkbox" v-on:change="checkedForm(index)"/>
...
</tbody>
```

Comment: For multi-checks, change the selected to array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your inputParams(where you bind your checkboxes), it provides how many indexes checked or unchecked.